# Flex element just keep expanding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a block element,
I want to change the element to flex and add it no wrap,

now when I change the element to flex, the items inside it just keep expanding the entire page,

**I don't want to change my entire project**

and I don't want to have to use fixed width,

why doesn't the flex element behave just like block element?

```
     <div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
          }}>
          {chips.map((option, index) => {
            return (
              <Tooltip
                key={option.name}
                title={isChipFoundInOptions ? '' : 'Option not found in this profile context.'}>
                <Chip
                  label={`${option.displayName} - ${option.name}`}
                  //   {...getChipProps({ index })}
                />
              </Tooltip>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you add an example image or a minimal sandbox please?

Comment: Please can you provide more details about your issue?

Comment: I am trying.
 thank you for your help.

Comment: The thing is,
after  this element, the element
just won't stop expanding, I want to limit it,
in display:block it was automated and in flex the element just keep expanding,
I want it to not wrap but I want it with a scrollbar,

Comment: _"but I want it with a scrollbar"_ - so add `overflow: auto` then.

Comment: thank you for you help, for some reason it doesn't work in my project,
and just keep expanding every single element

Comment: Can you post something that shows what you have now and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I want the flex element behave like a  block element, and know when to scroll and not keep expanding my page to the side,
sadly, I can't really post a picture from py proejct,
but thank you for your help anyway